# Proving the consistency of $\{\neg \forall v_{1}Pv_{1}, Pv_{2}, Pv_{3}, \dots \}$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I am trying to prove the consistency of $\Gamma = \{\neg \forall v_{1}Pv_{1}, Pv_{2}, Pv_{3}, \dots \}$. What I'm thinking is the following:

Suppose $\Gamma$ is inconsistent. $\{\neg \forall v_{1}Pv_{1}, Pv_{2}\}$ is consistent, so there must be a minimal $k \geq 2$ such that $\{\neg \forall v_{1}Pv_{1}, Pv_{2},\dots, Pv_{k+1} \}$ is inconsistent. By Reductio Ad Absurdum, this means $\{\neg \forall v_{1}Pv_{1}, Pv_{2},\dots, Pv_{k}\} \vdash \neg Pv_{k+1}$.

I want to show that $\{\neg \forall v_{1}Pv_{1}, Pv_{2},\dots, Pv_{k}\}$ is also inconsistent, contradicting the minimality of $k$, but am not sure how to do that -- it seems like I would do this by showing $\{\neg \forall v_{1}Pv_{1}, Pv_{2},\dots, Pv_{k}\} \vdash Pv_{k+1}$, but I don't have any insight right now as to how to show that.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the logic is classical first-order. Are you required to solve this problem within some proof theory? If not the following thoughts may help.

Any satisfiable set is consistent.So it suffices to show that $\Gamma$ is satisfied by some model. This can be shown via compactness: Let $\Gamma_0 \subseteq \Gamma$ be finite and so for some $n \in \mathbb{N}, \Gamma_0 \subseteq \Delta :=\lbrace \neg \forall v_1 Pv_1 \rbrace \cup \lbrace Pv_i : 1<i < n \rbrace$. Obviously $\Delta$ is satisfiable and consequently the same holds for $\Gamma_0$. 
`

Comment: So we're currently working through the proof of the Completeness Theorem in class, and so I dont think we can use that fact (or compactness for that matter). Also, the second part of the problem is to show whether or not the set of formulas is satisfiable.